# ImportError: No module named gerencia.alert.views

Tags: django, python-2.7

Estou tentando utilizar a seguinte função definida em `gerencia/alert/views.py`

```
def maLogger(level, message, node=None):

    aux=0
    if level=='Critical_client':
    aux=2
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    log = Log(level=level, date=date, node=node, message=message, flood=aux)
    log.save()
```

Já tentei chamá-la do arquivo `mad_weka.py` mas dá erro no import

```
[wilker@centos7 gerencia]$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 15 2016, 22:37:39) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mad_weka import Mad
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mad_weka.py", line 7, in <module>
    from gerencia.alert.views import maLogger
ImportError: No module named gerencia.alert.views
```

Abaixo segue a árvore de diretórios

```
[wilker@centos7 MeshAdmin]$ tree
    .
    ├── gerencia
    │   ├── alert
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.py
    │   │   ├── models.pyc
    │   │   ├── tests.py
    │   │   ├── urls.py
    │   │   ├── urls.pyc
    │   │   ├── views.py
    │   │   └── views.pyc
    │   ├── mad_weka.py
    │   ├── mad_weka.pyc
    │   ├── manage.py
    │   ├── mad
    │   │   ├── admin.py
    │   │   ├── admin.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   │   ├── mad_weka.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.py
    │   │   ├── models.pyc
    │   │   ├── tests.py
    │   │   └── views.py
```

Ainda que eu coloque no diretório `/mad` ou no próprio `/alert`, recebo o mesmo erro. O que preciso fazer para o Python enxergue o arquivo `views.py`?

---

Segue o link do [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/G87znuj9) com a árvore diretório completa.

Comment: Implementou minha resposta? Conseguiu?

Comment: @Sidon desculpe a demora, só posso mexer neste projeto a noite. Editei e coloquei a árvore completa no pastebin.

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso em seu diretório home:

```
$ mkdir teste1
$ cd teste1
$ mkdir gerencia
$ touch gerencia/__init__.py
$ mkdir gerencia/alert
$ touch gerencia/alert/__init__.py
```

A árvore deve ficar assim:

```
.
└── gerencia
    ├── alert
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── views.py
    └── __init__.py
```

Com um editor de texto crie um arquivo `views.py` em `gerencia/alert`. usando o vim no exemplo abaixo:

```
vim gerencia/alert/views.py

def hello():
    print ('Hello World!')
```

Agora teste o import no terminal python:

```
$ python
>>> from gerencia.alert.views import hello
>>> hello()
Hello World!
```

Não dá para ter certeza pela 'árvore' que vc postou, provavelmente esteja faltando `__init.py__` no ramo `gerencia`.

> Edidtada
>   No exemplo acima a chamada `from gerencia.alert.views import hello` leva em considerção que o terminal python foi chamado a partir da "raiz" da árvore, se vc estiver no mesmo diretorio onde se encontra o `.py` do qual vc quer fazer o import então o comando deve ser difetente, por exemplo:

```
$ cd gerencia\alert
$ python
>>> from views import hello
>>> hello()
Hello World!
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. 
De fato, há um arquivo __init__.py no diretório gerência. Não achei que a omissão deste fosse fazer diferença. O projeto é um pouco grande, e por isso omiti algumas linhas da árvore que pensei serem desnecessárias, pois passava do limite de caracteres da postagem.
As coloquei no [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/G87znuj9)

Comment: Esse import funcionou sim. Porém não peguei como utilizar este para montar o outro.

Comment: Para fazer import o diretorio e todos os "filhos" dos quais vc quer fazer import tem que ter o arquivo `__init.py__ `, mesmo que vazios. Basta criar esse arquivo nos diretorios (e seus filhos) dos quais vc quer fazer o import. Nem precisa abrir um editor para isso, crie com o comando `touch` como eu fiz na resposta.

Comment: E não pode ser somente `init.py` precisar iniciar e terminar com duplo undescore.

Comment: Criei os arquivos em todos os diretórios do projeto. Exceto template e media. E ainda assim não funcionou. :/

Comment: Olhando no raw do seu pastbin, percebi que `mad_weka.py`, está no mesmo diretório da view q vc quer fazer o import, então esse import deve ter outro formato, editei a resposta para explicar isso. Outra possibilidade é que seus `__init__.py` estejam corrompidos.

Comment: Entendo. Essa parte com relação ao diretório de importação separados por pontos ou não eu sabia. Mas acho pertinente. Obrigado pela ajuda. Pode ser que algum dos `__init__.py` estejam corrompidos. Mas por hora, vou mover o script para o diretório raiz e utilizar como solução paliativa, por conta do tempo curto que tenho. Após ter certeza que está funcionando corretamente tentarei alocá-lo no lugar que pensei originalmente.

Comment: Legal, Já que o problema foi solucionado, considere dar o aceite na resposta (sinal próximo ao número de votos). Obrigado.

Comment: Deixei aí meu upvote, vou deixar em aberto ainda, pois apesar de estar funcionando, o problema inicial ainda persiste. Só utilizei esta solução para que possa avançar na resolução e não ficar travado.

Comment: Acredite, não existe outra solução, ou seus `__init__.py` estão corrompidos ou tem algo errado no seu sistema de arquivos, a melhor maneira de comprovar isto é com exemplos minimalistas como eu ofereci na resposta. Se ainda restam dúvidas, [dê uma lida na documentação.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)